# Formula for Follow-up date with two separate criteria

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

To the point: I've built out a formula that calculates the follow-up date for when a client is due for a particular exam (in months):

```
=DATE(YEAR(C3)+0,MONTH(C3)+F3,DAY(C3))
```

What I've been trying to do is have this formula modified so that if another date were to be added to cell I3, that it utilizes the new cell (I3) as the date for which the follow-up should occur instead of the existing one.

Would I be able to do this in a formula?

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. What is in cell I3?

Comment: Cell I3 is left blank unless there is a date to enter. Lets assume we are talking about diagnostic exams, where C3 would be the "initial screening exam" and I3 would be "further evaluation if needed" There will not always be a date to enter into I3 but what I'm looking for is the option to do so and have the cell F3 respond to I3 instead of C3 when there is date to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean if I3 is blank, use the date in C3, but if you put a date in I3, use that one instead. So that would be this:

`=IF(I3>0,DATE(YEAR(C3)+0,MONTH(C3)+F3,DAY(C3),DATE(YEAR(I3)+0,MONTH(I3)+F3,DAY(I3))`

Comment: I was posting an answer that looked almost like yours but deleted it after I saw yours was a few seconds ahead of mine. The only change I would make is to check if I3 > 0. Otherwise text letters in I3 would cause problems.

Comment: @dev1998 Hi dev- thanks for that! I did see that both of our answers went up at the same time but I couldn't tell who was first. I made your suggested edit.

Comment: I tried this but it's returning that there are too many arguments :(

Comment: @dwirony 

So I KIND of got it to work. With a little messing around

=IF(I3<0,DATE(YEAR(D3)+0,MONTH(D3)+G3,DAY(D3)),DATE(YEAR(I3)+0,MONTH(I3)+G3,DAY(I3)))

The value does change when I enter a date into I3 and it is correct. However, when no data is entered into I3 it returns a date with year 1900

Comment: @NeftaliPerez When no data is in `I3` it should just be using the date in `C3`.